# Scikit-learn's Kernel PCA: How to implement an anisotropic Gaussian kernel or any other custom kernels in KPCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently using the [Scikit-learn's KPCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html) to perform dimensionality reduction on my dataset. They have the isotropic Gaussian kernel (RBF kernel) which only has one value gamma. But now, I want to implement an anisotropic Gaussian kernel that has many values of gamma that depend on the number of dimensions.

I'm aware that Kernel PCA has an option for **precomputed** kernel but I couldn't find any code example of it being used for dimensionality reduction.

Does anyone know how to implement a custom kernel in sklearn KPCA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem.

First of all, you have to define your own kernel function that returns the gram matrix between the samples.

```
def customkernel(X1,X2,etc):
    k = yourkernelfunction(X1,X2,etc)
    return k
```

If we want to fit a dataset ***x*** with size ***n x m*** into our KernelPCA model and transform it into ***n x n_princomp***, what we need is

```
KPCA = kpca(n_princomp,kernel='precomputed')
gram_mat = customkernel(x,x)
transformed_x = KPCA.fit_transform(gram_mat)
```

Next, if we want to transform another dataset ***X*** with size ***N x m*** into ***N x n_princomp*** what we have to do is calculating a new gram matrix with X as X1 and x as X2.

```
new_gram_mat = customkernel(X,x)
transformed_X = KPCA.transform(new_gram_mat)
```